# "java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)" is incomplete or malformed

Tags: database, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I have installed Oracle XE 11g version in Red Hat Linux. I followed the [steps here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL133). The Oracle is getting installed successfully and I can use the database. But while trying to run Java store procedure its showing that the Java is malformed.

Store procedure -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_java_sleep (milli_seconds IN NUMBER) AS     
       LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)';
```

Result:

```
Error(1,68): PLS-00311: the declaration of "java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)" is incomplete or malformed
```

Java 1.6 is installed in the Linux box.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Express Edition does not support Java in the database.  You can see all the edition differences [here](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/enterprise-edition/comparisons/index.html).

Take a look at the [Oracle Technology Network License Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html).  Chances are good that you can use a higher edition for personal development, for free.  Very few people need to use Express Edition.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But how come I can run the same procedure in windows machine in oracle xe?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Maybe it's a "bug" on Windows.  Normally Oracle makes all features easily available and trusts people to pay for them later.  It wouldn't surprise me if Express Edition wasn't thoroughly "locked down".  As an alternative, have you tried using `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP`?